# DNS nameserver for a specific domain

Tags: linux, dns

I need to be able to resolve one domain via a specific DNS server, while everything should be resolved by other DNS server(s). For example, resolve bbc.co.uk via 1.1.1.1 DNS server, but everything else by 8.8.8.8 . Is it possible?

Comment: No... DNS is hierarchical, and `co.uk` is asked who is responsible for `bbc`, the answer is valid for everybody.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  What is the application?  It sounds a little hokey to me.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to configure a DNS server that contains a forward lookup zone for example.com (I wouldn't mess with bbc.co.uk, sounds a little nefarious,) a forwarder to 8.8.8.8, and appropriate A and/or CNAME records.

Otherwise you might have an easier time changing the [hosts file](http://www.accs-net.com/hosts/hostsforlinux.html).

Comment: NOTE:  This only works if the user controls his machine and has root level access.